# Why Liveness / Readiness probe of airflow-flower pod failed?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy Airflow to Kubernetes cluster via Helm chart `apache-airflow/airflow:1.5.0`. I get errors in `airflow-flower-*` pod:

```
Readiness probe errored: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "23ece1d0a3bf7e9dc06f8e70cfb0e1d69687e2cbea952f18da7b4e80a2211995": OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: error executing setns process: exit status 1: unknown

Readiness probe failed: % Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5555: Connection refused

Liveness probe failed: % Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5555: Connection refused
```

The probe is `curl localhost:5555`. My `override-values.yaml` looks like:

```
extraSecrets:
  airflow-postgresql-metadata:
    data: "$AIRFLOW_POSTGRESQL_METADATA"
  airflow-postgresql-result-backend:
    data: "$AIRFLOW_POSTGRESQL_RESULT_BACKEND"

data:
  metadataSecretName: airflow-postgresql-metadata
  resultBackendSecretName: airflow-postgresql-result-backend


workers:
  persistence:
    enabled: false
  resources:
    limits:
     cpu: 100m
     memory: 128Mi
    requests:
     cpu: 100m
     memory: 128Mi
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa

scheduler:
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa

webserver:
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa

flower:
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 128Mi     
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 128Mi
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa

statsd:
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 128Mi     
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 128Mi
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa

cleanup:
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa

createUserJob:
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa

migrateDatabaseJob:
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa

triggerer:
  enabled: false
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa

rbac:
  create: false

redis:
  persistence:
    storageClassName: "ceph-rbd-ssd"
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa

postgresql:
  enabled: false
```

That is, I changed almost nothing, I just set resource limits and disabled the creation of service accounts. Why can these probes fall?

Also I'm interested in the minimal version of the `values.yaml` file to deploy an AirFlow

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer to the question asked, but solve the problem

I turned off the flower, but I kept getting the same errors from another pod. According to the logs of the pod I found out that there is nothing happened at all. I thought it was a lack of resources - and it turned out

This values.yaml works for me:

```yaml
extraSecrets: 
  airflow-postgresql-metadata:
    data: "$AIRFLOW_POSTGRESQL_METADATA"
  airflow-postgresql-result-backend:
    data: "$AIRFLOW_POSTGRESQL_RESULT_BACKEND"


# Airflow database & redis config
data:
  metadataSecretName: airflow-postgresql-metadata
  resultBackendSecretName: airflow-postgresql-result-backend


# Airflow Worker Config
workers:
  replicas: 1
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa
  keda:
    enabled: false
  persistence:
    enabled: false
  kerberosSidecar:
    enabled: false
  resources:
   limits:
    cpu: 1000m
    memory: 2048Mi
   requests:
    cpu: 1000m
    memory: 2048Mi
  logGroomerSidecar:
    enabled: false


# Airflow scheduler settings
scheduler:
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa
  resources:
   limits:
    cpu: 1000m
    memory: 2048Mi
   requests:
    cpu: 1000m
    memory: 2048Mi
  logGroomerSidecar:
    enabled: false


# Airflow webserver settings
webserver:
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa
  podDisruptionBudget:
    enabled: false
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 1000m
      memory: 2048Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 1000m
      memory: 2048Mi


# Airflow Triggerer Config
triggerer:
  enabled: true
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa
  resources:
   limits:
    cpu: 1000m
    memory: 2048Mi
   requests:
    cpu: 1000m
    memory: 2048Mi


# StatsD settings
statsd:
  enabled: true
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 1000m
      memory: 2048Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 1000m
      memory: 2048Mi


# Configuration for the redis provisioned by the chart
redis:
  enabled: true
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa
  persistence:
    enabled: false
  resources:
   limits:
    cpu: 1000m
    memory: 2048Mi
   requests:
    cpu: 1000m
    memory: 2048Mi


# Airflow create user job settings
createUserJob:
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 1000m
      memory: 2048Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 1000m
      memory: 2048Mi


# Airflow database migration job settings
migrateDatabaseJob:
  enabled: true
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: srs-khajiit-airflow-sa
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 1000m
      memory: 2048Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 1000m
      memory: 2048Mi


cleanup:
  enabled: false

postgresql:
  enabled: false

pgbouncer:
  enabled: false

dags:
  persistence:
    enabled: false
  gitSync:
    enabled: false

dagProcessor:
  enabled: false

flower:
  enabled: false

logs:
  persistence:
    enabled: false

elasticsearch:
  enabled: false

kerberos:
  enabled: false

ingress:
  enabled: false
  web:
    enabled: false
  flower:
    enabled: false
    
networkPolicies:
  enabled: false

rbac:
  create: false
  createSCCRoleBinding: false
```

Comment: So what are the changes you made in your yaml to solve this issue ?